# Explain unexpected program output

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    final static int x = 2;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (int z=0; z < 3; z++) {
            switch (z) {
                case x: System.out.print("0 ");
                case x-1: System.out.print("1 ");
                case x-2: System.out.print("2 ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a variable called X which holds the value 2 however my output is `2 1 2 0 1 2`.

Why do I get this unexpected output and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you heard about [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you debug your code (which I highly recommend!), you'll see that when writing a switch statement without breaking the cases (using the `break` keyword at the end of each case), it flows from case to case.

In your code, `x` is always equals 2, so in the first run, only the last case is met and you print out `2`.

In the second iteration, when `z=1`, the middle case is met and so you print `1`. However, since you don't break, it continues to execute the code of the next case as well, printing `2` again.

In the third and last iteration, `z=2` and the first case is met, but since you never `break;`, all cases are executed and you print `0 1 2`.

Answer (score 2):

its simple 
`switch` statement will hold your variable `z` whose value ranges from `0 to 2` as your loop defining;
now when the value of `z` matches with any `case` then the code it has, will run also when any case gets true all the following cases will also run due to missing `break` statement

**First Iteration:**

`z=0`,`x=2`

last `case x-2:` gets true

```
output: 2
```

**Second Iteration:**

`z=1`,`x=2`

`case x-1:` gets true but the last case also triggered

```
output: 2 1 2
```

**Third Iteration:**

`z=2`,`x=2`

`case x:` gets true also the following two cases get triggered

```
output: 2 1 2 0 1 2



    public class Test
    {final static int x = 2;
        public static void main(String [] args){
            for (int z=0; z < 3; z++){
                switch (z){
                    case x: // it appears case 2:
                       System.out.print("0 ");
                       // break; you need break statement here
                    case x-1: //it appears to be case 1:
                       System.out.print("1 ");
                       // break; you need break statement here
                    case x-2: // it appears to be case 0:
                       System.out.print("2 ");
                       // break; you need break statement here
}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a break statement after every case and the reason for this is because when any of the cases gets true then the cases following it are also executed if there is no break statement present.